# Annotation processing with kapt Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, java-annotations, kapt

I'm trying to use kapt for using my annotation processor. But I ran into a few problems.

Annotation processor jar is connected this way:

```
    kapt files('libs/processor.jar')
    provided files('libs/processor.jar')
```

1) I'm using [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) for code generation. And saving my class this way

```
    JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder(PACKAGE, typeSpec).build();
    javaFile.writeTo(processingEnv.getFiler());
```

But it always saves it to build\generated\source\kapt\release, and never to debug folder regardless of build variant.

[image]

2) The second problem is that generated file sometimes doesn't refresh, until I press Build->Rebuild

Comment: have you found a solution to this? Hitting the same issue.

Comment: @david.schreiber the problem with folder was "solved" by using processor only in application module. The problem with the file updates remained. Are you using kotlin 1.0.6, maybe they fixed these issues in kapt?

Comment: I also had issues with library modules, but after analyzing gradle outputs, I noticed that only release sources were built. The reason for this is, that by default, library modules will only publish release artifacts: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication I added my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kotlin-kapt` plugin will automatically select the correct output directory based on the built library/application variant. When building a project with a single `com.android.application` module, Android Studio will use the application variant selected in the "Build Variants" menu.

[image: Build variants window]

This is not true for library modules, which, if not configured otherwise, will publish the `release` build variant – even when you select "debug" for those modules inside the "Build Variants" menu.

To get `kapt` up and running for library modules, you have three options:

1. In the "Build Variants" window, select "release" for the library module containing your annotated code. This will tell Android Studio to pick up the `kapt` output inside `generated/sources/kapt/release/`.
2. In your library modules `build.gradle` set the `defaultPublishConfig` to `debug` (and keep the selected variant at debug too). This will tell the Android Gradle plugin to compile the `debug` library variant instead of the default `release` one.

   ```
   android {
       defaultPublishConfig "debug"
   }
   ```
3. You can also choose to publish both the `debug` and `release` build variants ant the same time, by setting `publishNonDefaults` to `true`. In your main app module, you can then reference the library module twice, for `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile` configurations. However, note that this will *always* build both types, even though you might only require debug sources at the time of building, practically doubling compile times.